# Laravel Eloquent ORM - Complex where queries

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm, where-clause

I have the following query:

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM mod_dns_records WHERE (scheduled = 'N' AND scheduleTime = 0 AND domainId = {$id}) OR (deleteRow = 'Y' AND domainId = {$id})");
```

However, this is not safe against SQL injection. Could someone help me to make this safe, or tell me how to rebuild this with the ORM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would be the query as you had it

```
$result = DB::table('mod_dns_records')
            ->where('scheduled', 'N')
            ->where('scheduleTime', 0)
            ->where('domainId', $id)
            ->orWhere('deleteRow', 'Y')
            ->where('domainId', $id)
            ->get();
```

However I noticed it can be optimized a bit since the `domainId` condition exists in both groups:

```
$result = DB::table('mod_dns_records')
            ->where('domainId', $id)
            ->where(function($q){
                $q->where('scheduled', 'N');
                $q->where('scheduleTime', 0);
                $q->orWhere('deleteRow', 'Y');
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: Note that first example works only because OR has lower priority than AND -- it does not add any grouping parentheses like in the original query in question. On the other hand, where(...callback...) in the second example does add parentheses.