# Laravel eloquent query building using OR

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, eloquent

This `eloquent` query filter:

```
return $this->games()
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('active_player_id', '=', $this->id)
                ->where('stage_name', '<>', 'setup');
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->where('active_player_id', '<>', $this->id)
                ->where('stage_name', '=', 'setup');
        });
```

Builds into SQL like this:

```
where `games_players`.`player_id` = '1' 
and (`active_player_id` = '1' and `stage_name` <> 'setup') 
or (`active_player_id` <> '1' and `stage_name` = 'setup')
```

How do I change the `eloquent` code to build this query (brackets around the `OR`):

```
where `games_players`.`player_id` = '1' 
and (
     (`active_player_id` = '1' and `stage_name` <> 'setup') 
  or (`active_player_id` <> '1' and `stage_name` = 'setup')
    )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent ORM - Complex where queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036959/laravel-eloquent-orm-complex-where-queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by doing this:

```
    ->where('active_player_id',1)
    ->where(function($q){
          $q->where([ ['active_player_id', 1],['stage_name','!=', 'setup'] ])
            ->orWhere([ ['active_player_id','!=', 1],['stage_name', 'setup'] ]
    })->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an instance of Eloquent to hand to test against just now but would it now be something like this?

```
return $this->games()
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('active_player_id', '=', $this->id)
                ->where('stage_name', '<>', 'setup');
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->where('active_player_id', '<>', $this->id)
                ->where('stage_name', '=', 'setup');
        })
    })
;
```

That is, you put the conditions to be grouped together into an anonymous function on where?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `orWhere` condition into the first anonymous function like this,

```
return $this->games()
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('active_player_id', '=', $this->id)
                ->where('stage_name', '<>', 'setup')
            ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                $query->where('active_player_id', '<>', $this->id)
                    ->where('stage_name', '=', 'setup');
        });
        })
```